# how to update multiple record using ajax using checbox in laravel php?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, laravel

consider i have `csid = [1 , 2 , 3]` and `area_id = 10` i want to assign area id to cs id
so i tried this code

this code get all user ids in  (`var ids = []`) and get `area-select` and pass to ajax but it response **500 error**

```
$('#change_area_multiple').on('click', function () { // perform action 
    var ids = []
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="changearea[]"]:checked') // get all checked value of user id
        
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        ids.push(checkboxes[i].value) // push all ids
    }
    console.log(ids);
    var areaselected = document.getElementById("area-select").value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '{{ route('change.area.multiple') }}',
        data: {'areaselected': areaselected, 'user_id': ids},
        success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.message);
        }
    });
});
```

route

```
 Route::get('/area/updatemultiple', 'CustomerController@updatemultipleareas')->name('change.area.multiple');
```

controller

```
public function updatemultipleareas(Request $request)          
{
    for ($i = 0; i < sizeof($request->user_id); $i++) {
        $customer = Customer::find($request->user_id[i]);
        $customer->area_id = $request->areaselected;
        $customer->save();
    }
    return response()->json(['message' => 'User status updated successfully.']);
    
}
```

i think my controller logic is wrong ? can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

found solution

```
 public function updatemultipleareas(Request $request)
        
        {
            $deli = $request->get('user_id');
            foreach($deli as $us_id) {
            $customer = Customer::find($us_id);
            $customer->area_id = $request->areaselected;
            $customer->save();
            }
            return response()->json(['message' => 'User status updated successfully.']);
            
        }
```